# Standalone package border option

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have a problem with standalone class:

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

The above MWE creates an unbalanced image: the right border is visibly smaller.
[image: right border is visibly smaller]

However, on the smaller rectangles, like 2cm-by-1cm the effect disappears.

Is it possible to fix the issue?

Comment: It looks [perfectly symmetric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyBex.png) on my machine. This seems like a PDF viewer problem unless you maybe use an older version which might have had this bug (but I doubt that it existed).

Comment: I have tested on `MacO$` with `TeXShop`. The output is good.

Comment: I have tested three different viewers - I can not recreate the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem can not be recreated

Comment: I'm using Overleaf, and indeed it is symmetric in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Comment: @dEmigOd: You can not trust a browser preview. All that counts is the actual pdf generated. From overleaf you can download the pdf and have a look at it yourself.